# Creating a manual admin user in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Hii I am running a website with Node.js + MongoDB . A freelancer helped me setting up all up and running , but now unfortunately is not responding .

I have a setup in which I remember him telling me that the first admin user will be created programatically and users can be created by the simple SignUp option . I am trying to test something on my local copy and since that local copy creates a fresh copy with only databases but no users . I was able to create a normal user through SignUp , but I am not able to create that admin user required .

I have no clue about how to work in MongoDB , but I tried to refer to the manual and tried following commands :

```
mongo -- shell : It made me enter the Mongo console .

show databases : Showed me two vix Automator and local . 

I know Automator must be mine since that's what my project is called .

Then I typed : use automator and entered the database

I typed there show collections ; and got the following output :

box
device
gcm
system.indexes
user
```

I guess user is the collection where I should be able to create admin and other users , But I am not sure if this is right and I don't know how . I already created a normal user with which am able to sign in on my local copy but I don't see that user anywhere too .

Continuing with my research I executed the following commands :

```
> var schematodo = db.user.findOne();
> for (var key in schematodo) { print (key) ; }


Output :

id
fullname
address
phone
city
state
country
email
admin
api
passwordFailures
encrypted_password
salt
createdAt
updatedAt
```

Tried db.user.find().pretty()

Output : I see  my normal test user details I created using the signup method . How can I create an admin with the same way ? Is it by setting the key Admin = true ?

Output :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c1c3d14635a3518d21d15"),
    "fullname" : "Diwesh Sacena",
    "address" : "Testing Lab",
    "phone" : "0106666666",
    "city" : "Seoul",
    "state" : "Seoul",
    "country" : "Korea",
    "email" : "tut@gmail.com",
    "admin" : false,
    "api" : false,
    "passwordFailures" : 0,
    "encrypted_password" : "$2a$06$U31sneJr6zudiY0eo79.7.cWCSBpfLGcCI7d2limq59V6RKNwXT9S",
    "salt" : "$2a$06$U31sneJr6zudiY0eo79.7.",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-25T15:20:29.225Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-06-25T15:20:29.225Z")
}
```

Also looking at the source code I found a file called User.js which contains the same schema info , Maybe you can look at this and help :(

User.js

```
/**
 * User.js
 *
 * @description ::
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
 */

module.exports = {

  schema: true,

  attributes: {
    fullname: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    email: {
      type: 'string',
      email: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },

    admin: {
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: false
    },

    api: {
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: false
    },

    state: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    city: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    country: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    address: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    phone: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    encrypted_password: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    salt: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    passwordFailures: {
      type: 'integer',
      defaultsTo: 0
    },

    lastPasswordFailure: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    resetToken: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    toJSON: function () {
      var obj = this.toObject();

      return {
        id: obj.id,
        fullname: obj.fullname,
        admin: obj.admin
      }
    },

    validatePassword: function (password, next) {
      if (!password || password.length === 0) {
        return next(null, false);
      }

      var obj = this.toObject();

      UserManager.hashPassword(password, obj.salt, function (err, hashedPassword) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        next(null, hashedPassword === obj.encrypted_password);
      })
    }
  },

  beforeCreate: function (values, next) {
    if (!values.password || values.password != values.confirmation) {
      return next({
        message: "Password doesn't match password confirmation."
      })
    }

    var _salt = null;
    UserManager.hashPassword(values.password, _salt, function (err, password, salt) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      values.encrypted_password = password;
      values.salt = salt;
      next();
    })
  }
}
```

And these are are some more files in my source folder : If you think any of these is appropriate for you to check , let me know I can post that file too :

[image]

Please help how to proceed :(

Tried : `db.user.update({_id: ObjectId("558c1c3d14635a3518d21d15")},{admin: true})`

Output :

```
> db.user.update({_id: ObjectId("558c1c3d14635a3518d21d15")},{admin: true})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })


> db.user.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558c1c3d14635a3518d21d15"), "admin" : true }
```

But now I am not able to login with my id which was associated with this account . Also as you can see now find().pretty() replaced all details of the user , basically updated them :(

Comment: what's the output for `db.user.find().pretty()` ?

Comment: @hassansin : Hi added the output . Please help :(

Comment: so you can just promote a user to admin by doing this: 

`db.user.update({_id: ObjectId("558c1c3d14635a3518d21d15")},{admin: true})`

Comment: @Rahul You need to set `Admin = true` while creating user or update value of `Admin` to true for existing user.

Comment: @hassansin : Please check the edit to see the result of your suggestion . It didnt work :(

Comment: my bad, forgot the [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) operator. Try again for a new user

Comment: @hassansin: can you please rewrite the whole command with $set so I make sure I am putting it in the right place :(

Comment: @hassansin: Like this ? db.user.update({_id: ObjectId("558c1c3d14635a3518d21d15")},{ $set:{admin: true} })

Comment: yes, but for a new user.

Answer (score 0):

After seeking help from several experts I finally was able to solve the problem , though my case was more specific since my web program had certain functions where I could promote a normal user to admin . However I would like to post a quick reference which you can also get on MongoDb manual but these steps can be used sequentially to pull most of the data   .

```
mongo --shell : start momgo shell in terminal

show databases : shows all databases

show collections : shows all collections inside that database

db.collectionName.find().pretty() : shows the collection schema with complete details and existing data 


To make the first admin :

1. Make a normal user through signup 

2. db.user.update({_id: ObjectId("5593aa85dab6c3b33a853ef4")},{ $set:{admin: true} }) 

where ObjectID is can be seen from find().pretty()  and "user" is the name of your collection in the database .
```